# Combine assign(to:) with a @Published var

Tags: swift, combine

I have an enum in my project:

```
enum Remote<Content> {
  case .notAsked
  case .loading
  case .loaded(Content)
  case .failed(Error)
}
```

I then have a class:

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var content: Remote<ContentStruct> = .notAsked

  func fetchContent() {
    content = .loading

    service.fetchContent()
      .receive(on: queue)
      .map(Remote<ContentStruct>.loaded)
      .catch { error in Just(.failed(error)) }
      .assign(to: &self.content)
  }
}
```

But this complains to me that:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Remote<ContentStruct>' to expected argument type 'Published<Remote<ContentStruct>>.Publisher'
```

I can change it to use this:

```
func fetchContent() {
  content = .loading

  service.fetchContent()
    .receive(on: queue)
    .map(Remote<ContentStruct>.loaded)
    .catch { error in Just(.failed(error)) }
    .assign(to: \.content, on: self)
    .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

And this works and assigns the value correctly. But I don't understand why I can't use the `.assign(to: keyPath)` function on there?

Do I need to do something different? We've only recently updated to support a minimum of iOS14 and so not been using `assign(to:` before due to memory leaks and now I'm just not sure how this is working.

Thanks

Comment: The complaint is pretty straight forward. Can't assign your custom type value to a publisher. I would look into .flatMap to create a new publisher. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers-merge-publisher-operators

Comment: @cora I tried that by doing something like `.flatMap(Just.init)` but now it just adds a layer of `Published<Just<...>>.Publisher` to the error. Like I said, this is the first opportunity we've had to properly dive into using `assign` this way. It may be stupidly simple for you to resolve this but would be good to know how you might resolve it. I just am not sure what I'me doing wrong here. Thanks

Comment: @cora I'm not sure what extra details or clarity you would need in the question. You seem to understand what it is that I need to do from everything I have provided. You just haven't actually helped in any way by providing the knowledge that you have told me is "pretty straight forward".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`assign(to:)` requires a `Published.Publisher` as its input. So you need to pass the publisher from the `Publisher` property wrapper, which you can access using the `$` prefix.

```
.assign(to: &$content)
```

Comment: Ah! Of course! Thank you. I was seeing the & and mixing it up in my head with the $ from bindings and state etc... in SwiftUI so didn't expect to use both of them. Thanks

Comment: And with this now comes the understanding that `assign(to:on:)` and `assign(to:)` are fundamentally different things.  Learning is happening.